# In Memoriam: David Drake

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[David Drake](https://david-drake.com/), one of the most prominent mil-sf authors, [died December 10th, 2023](https://www.donaldsonfunerals.com/obituary/David-Drake).  His rise to prominence came with the [Hammer's Slammers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?11500) series of futuristic war stories, mostly short stories variously collected.

I will always remember his gritty, visceral, and unflinching take, not just on the horrors of war, but on the harrowing and dehumanizing effect it had on his protagonists.  Especially back in the day it stood in stark contrast to the kind of story where the hero would go off and slaughter aliens and mooks all morning, then come home for a hearty meal and some light romance.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to post this.  Blame the pressure of the holiday season.

Comment: Howard Waldrop and Terry Bisson are two other notable SF authors who recently passed I don't see posts for.

Comment: @Shawn I don't really know either of them (I recognize the names, but couldn't name anything I've read by either), and I'm trying not to spam the site with too many posts.  [A lot of people died in 2023](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=author_deathdate&O_1=contains&TERM_1=2023&C=AND&ORDERBY=author_deathdate&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Author), including some notable people (like Alan Arkin) who had minor writing credits.  But if you feel they deserve to be memorialized, go ahead.

Comment: It's also a bit of work (not to mention a bit depressing) to watch for death notifications, so sometimes people get completely missed.  Like we never had an in memoriam for [Eric Flint](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?3596) who was huge, not just as an author but also a contributor to the SF community.